# What does the repmgr the symbol "*" mean in the repmgr cluster status output?

Tags: postgresql, repmgr

I'm new to postgres administration and was wondering what does the "*" symbol means in the `repmgr cluster show` command output.

```
 ID | Name    | Role    | Status    | Upstream | Location | Connection string                                               
----+---------+---------+-----------+----------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | node-1  | standby |   running | node-2   | default  | host= [...] 
 2  | node-2  | primary | * running |          | default  | host= [...]
 3  | node-3  | witness | * running | node-2   | default  | host= [...]
```

I didn't find anything about it in the documentation (https://repmgr.org/docs/4.0/repmgr-cluster-show.html)

Using `repmgr cluster show --csv` as mentioned in the documentation, I can see that the node with ID 1 is in recovery state "*in recovery*". Is it related ?

postgresql version : 10.5
repmgr version : 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not documented, but the [code is here](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/repmgr/blob/b37a599fc659f10867a46a55fe2bd1acd4d638f8/repmgr-client.c#L2076); it looks like `* running` is used for the running state for primaries and witnesses, but not secondaries. I'm not sure how intended that is; it might have just been a copy/paste of the code block that was used for primary; [here's the relevant](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/repmgr/commit/a5c5d9fa40b29be94ea190eea75b7cd12e61ab44) commit that introduced the 2nd `* running` status string.